# ALTER SEQUENCE on rake db:reset db:migrate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-migration, user-management

I'm developing an information system in Ruby on Rails.

I want to hand out following uids to users:

```
0: root
1-499: system services (server-side)
500: system admin
501-999: external apps (apps that connect through API)
1000+: human users
```

I have the following migration set up:

```
class SetUsersAutoincrementValue < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute("ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1000")
  end
end
```

The migration works as expected. However, it doesn't if triggered by `rake db:reset db:migrate`.

What to do?

Thanks

Comment: after `rake db:reset`, I think the table will loose data.. Do you have migration to upload the data again.. ?

Comment: Indeed. This migration takes place right after `CreateUsers` migration.

Comment: Okay,... cool.. What do you mean by *not working* ? After doing `rake db:reset`.. could you tell me the count of the table rows, on which you applied the sequence change ?

Comment: Well, if I run it as a whole, it doesn't set the auto_increment value to 1000, however, if I create a new migration using `rails g migration SetPeopleAutoincrementValue --force` and paste the above code, then run `rake db:migrate`, it successfully sets the proper auto_increment...

Comment: That was not my question although. From doc I can see - *[ALTER SEQUENCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-altersequence.html) will not immediately affect nextval results in backends, other than the current one, that have preallocated (cached) sequence values. They will use up all cached values prior to noticing the changed sequence generation parameters. The current backend will be affected immediately.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose `rake db:migrate:reset`.

Comment: Your advice help me, when i'm upgraded to Rails 5.2.1. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart the ruby server (Puma) may help.

I run the SQL command `ALTER TABLE` directly on DB to change a table id column from INT to BIGINT.

After updating, when inserting big number I got an error `out of range for ActiveModel::Type::Integer with limit 4"`

After restart ruby server, everything works well.